# Dynamically change TextView in Fragment (public void processMessage)

Tags: android, textview, xmpp, fragment

I am looking for a way to create a chat fragment. So basically I am trying to make a fragment dynamic. As a first step I am trying to update a textview which I have to display messages received. I am using XMPP as a client and I am receiving message through the following function:

```
        @Override
        public void processMessage(Chat arg0, org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message message) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String from = message.getFrom();
            String body = message.getBody();
            System.out.println(String.format("Received message '%1$s' from %2$s", body, from));
            text.setText(String.format("'%1$s' from %2$s", body, from));
        }
```

Any help regarding dynamically updating a textview in a fragment is appreciated.

Thanks

Max

Comment: How actually do you work with fragment?

Comment: well I don't know what you want to know exactly, but I use the onCreateView to set up my UI and apart from that no other function is used.

Comment: I meant that you didn't show code that work with fragment. Ok, you can create method in you fragment e.g.: `updateText(String text)` that will interact with `TextView` that you can retrieve by using `findViewById` in you fragment. In you activity you can find you fragment using `myFragment = (MyFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(id)`. Then just invoke this method e.g.: `myFragment.updateText("new message");`

Comment: I though of this as well but findViewById only works in the onCreateView Method. In the method processmessage this is not recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of `MyFragment` that allow text update:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView textView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        return view;
    }

    public void updateTextValue(CharSequence newText) {
        textView.setText(newText);
    }
}
```

Example of `Activity` that holds the `MyFragment`:

```
public class Activity extends Activity {

    MyFragment myFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        myFragment = (MyFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentA);
    }

    @Override
    public void processMessage(Chat arg0, org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message message) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() {             
                myFragment.updateTextValue("Hi fragment!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in the end i figured it out the "myFragment.updateTextValue("Hi fragment!");" has to be put into a thread as follows runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                 myFragment.updateTextValue("Hi fragment!");
                }
            });

Answer (score 1):

In the processMessage() function, you can do `getView().findViewById(id_of_text_view);`

`getView()` returns the View created in `onCreateView()`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView%28%29